# LinkGenerator.GetUriByAction not following the custom route

Tags: api, asp.net-core, controller

That's the controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")
public class MarketController : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpGet("{id}/picture")
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetPictureAsync(Guid id)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm using LinkGenerator to create a Absolute URI from GetPictureAsync. And set the Startup class to start HttpContextAccessor as DI.

```
// Startup.cs
...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ...
  services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
  ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  ...
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
  });
}
```

And in my custom class I use that way:

```
public class CustomClass
{
  private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
  private readonly LinkGenerator _linkGenerator;

  public CustomClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
    LinkGenerator linkGenerator)
  {
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    _linkGenerator = linkGenerator;
  }

  public void SomeMethod()
  {
    var uri = _linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext, "GetPicture", "Markets", new { id = id });
  }

}
```

The problem is because LinkGenerator is not following the custom route sample that I set in GetPicture method.

**The LinkGenerator generates the following value:**

`https://localhost:5051/Markets/GetPicture/00748d23-afa7-4efb-b67b-77f68fdc44d5`

**But it should generate:**

`https://localhost:5051/api/Markets/00748d23-afa7-4efb-b67b-77f68fdc44d5/picture`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The reason is you use wrong controller name in `SomeMethod`.* Follow the steps you provided, I reproduced your issue.

## You should use `Market`, not `Markets`.

Because your controller name is `MarketController`.

**After test it,it works for me.**

[image]

[image]